# document.readyState for a popup window is always "complete" in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

A simple test: if I open developer tools on this page and run this command in Chrome:

```
window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', 'newWindowName').document.readyState
```

I see the output:

> "complete"

which looks wrong to me since the window clearly didn't load yet. I see more sane output in other browsers - I checked Firefox and IE.

My question is: is there any other way to be notified when a created window's DOM is ready in Chrome? It's not cross origin, so I should be able to access the window's properties. Also, I'm aware that there's the `DOMContentLoaded` event, but it fires only once, and doesn't work again if I re-use the same window (in my example, using the name "newWindowName") to get notified when a new page's DOM is ready.